# SASS Using a variable list to fill arguments in a mixin

Tags: css, sass

I am building locally a mixin for linear gradients specific for a project. The idea is that I have 6 different gradient schemes going on. I am trying to pass all of the values for the arguments from a variable. Not sure if I am going beyond what SASS supports right now. Also all 3 are in separate files that are imported into the master site scss file.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
$gradientBlue: #68bafa, #279bf2, #2891e2;

@mixin verticalGradient($color-1, $color-2, $color-3: "", $color-4: "", $color-5: "" ) {
  background: $color-1;
  @include pie;
  @include filter-gradient($color-1, $color-2);  
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, $color-1 0%, $color-2 100%));
  @if #{$color-3} != none {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #{$color-3};
  }
  @if #{$color-4} != none {   
    &:hover {
      @include pie;
      background: $color-4;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px $color-5;
    } 
  }
}

@include verticalGradient($gradientBlue);
```

Comment: Also, read about [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_). You're sort of going crazy with it, I can't imagine a place where you'd want to use it with the `@if` directive. It's more for selector and property names.

Comment: You may want to consider having your solid background color set to `mix($color-1, $color-2)`.  In my own work, I found that it looked nicer as a fallback than going with either of the stop colors.  On the other hand, you may find that there are instances where the 2nd stop is a more appropriate background color than the 1st stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Try something like this:

```
$gradientBlue: #68bafa, #279bf2, #2891e2;

@mixin vertical-gradient($colors) {    
  @include background(linear-gradient(nth($colors, 1), nth($colors, 2)));
  @if length($colors) >= 3 {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px nth($colors, 3);
  }
  @if length($colors) >= 4 {
    background: nth($colors, 4);
  }
}

body {
  @include vertical-gradient($gradientBlue);
}
```

Comment: If you were going for a literal translation of the OP's mixin, the background color was set to the 1st color.  The hover's background is the 4th color.

Comment: I was just going for a simplified example of the concept, if you want to edit it so he can copy and paste, feel free. :-)

Comment: I didn't know about the nth() option. Points and much appreciation go to you, ser.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue, 
i wrote an mixin which should assign a list of parameters to a compass mixin.
and here is my solution ( with compass 0.12.2):

```
@mixin single-box-shadow-fallback( $color, $arg... ) {
  @include single-box-shadow( $color, $arg... );
    .lt-ie9 & {
      border: 1px solid $color;
    }
  }
}
```

call

```
@include single-box-shadow-fallback( #CCC, 0, 0, 2px, 0, true );
```

---

these example output an wront css;

```
@mixin single-box-shadow-fallback( $color, $arg ) {
  @include single-box-shadow( $color, $arg );
}
```

output:

```
  box-shadow: 0, 0, 2px, 0, true 0px 5px #cccccc;
```